# In context of WAS, what is the difference between application bounce and jvm bounce

Tags: websphere

In context of WAS, what is the difference between application bounce and jvm bounce.

In case we only want to reload the data at server startup , whch one should we go for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same application can be restarted multiple times while a server is running.  If you only want to load data once per server start, then I would recommend placing a class in a shared library associated with a server class loader.  This will make it accessible to all applications, and the static variables will retain their contents until the server is restarted.  Of course, this also means you cannot update these classes without restarting the server.